# How to correctly filter a clause that returns multiple duplicated values?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to correctly filter the values returned from a clause (it is returning multiple duplicated values). I'm having a hard time understanding the logic programming, sorry if its an stupid question.

These are my facts/predicates:

```
home(peter, sanFrancisco, 1000).
home(ash, sanFrancisco, 100).
home(juan, sanFrancisco, 400).
home(juan, california, 700).
home(ash, california, 600).
home(peter, california, 500).
home(peter, vegas, 100).
home(ash, vegas, 80).
home(juan, vegas, 60).
```

What im trying to do is to retrieve the name; the condition is that I have to retrieve only the ones that from a certain city their home is the most expensive from there but also if the second most expensive home from that same city is less than half the price of the first. I cannot use lists.

The most expensive from each city:

```
home(peter, sanFrancisco, 1000).
home(juan, california, 700).
home(peter, vegas, 100).
```

Second most expensive from each city:

```
home(juan, sanFrancisco, 400).
home(ash, california, 600).
home(ash, vegas, 80).
```

What I expect as a result:

```
peter.
```

What I have tried so far but with no success..

```
%Return the most expensive from each city.
theMostExpensive(Name, City):-
    home(Name, City, Price),
    fromEach(City, Price).

fromEach(City, Price):-
    forall(home(_, City, Price2), Price>= Price2).

%Return the second most expensive from each city. Not sure if working correctly.
secondMostExpensive(Name, City):-
    owner(home),
    not(theMostExpensive(Name, City)),
    theMostExpensive(Name2, City),
    Name \= Name2.

%Return a lot of duplicated values and wrong..
superExpensive(Name):-
    theMostExpensive(Name, City),
    secondMostExpensive(Name2, City),
    Name \= Name2,
    City \= City2,
    home(Name, City, Price),
    home(Name2, City2, Price2),
    Price > Price2 + (Price / 2).
```

I think somewhere in superExpensive is doing something like everyone * everyone?

Comment: I cannot understand `only the ones that from a certain city their home is the most expensive from there but also if the second most expensive home from that same city is less than half the price of the first`. Maybe rephrase it in correct nglish... Anyway, the most general query `?- secondMostExpensive(X,Y).` is false. Is this expected ?

Comment: @CapelliC, I have to compare the most expensive and the second most expensive home from each city and get the name only if the most expensive is at least double the second. `secondMostExpensive(X, Y) forgot to add owner(Name),` but im not certain its working well when passing values (free variables works fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most expensive home in a town is such that no other home in that town is more expensive than it:

```erlang
most_expensive( home( Name, Town, Price)):-
  home( Name, Town, Price),
  \+ (home( _, Town, P), P > Price).
```

This gets us

```erlang
5 ?- most_expensive( H ).
H = home(peter, sanFrancisco, 1000) ;
H = home(juan, california, 700) ;
H = home(peter, vegas, 100) ;
false.
```

The second most expensive home in a town is such that is the most expensive among the homes which are not the most expensive home in that town:

```erlang
second_most_expensive( home( Name, Town, Price)):-
  most_expensive( home( _, Town, TopPrice) ),
  home( Name, Town, Price), Price < TopPrice,
  \+ (home( _, Town, P), P < TopPrice, P > Price).
```

And this gets us

```erlang
8 ?- second_most_expensive( H ).
H = home(juan, sanFrancisco, 400) ;
H = home(ash, california, 600) ;
H = home(ash, vegas, 80) ;
false.
```

So then, with

```erlang
top_house_owner( Name ) :-
  most_expensive( home( Name, T, P) ),
  second_most_expensive( home( _, T, P2 ) ),
  P2 < P div 2.
```

we get

```erlang
12 ?- top_house_owner( N ).
N = peter ;
false.
```

Comment: What if I want to do the same but calculating the Price inside the clause? Like `second_most_expensive( Name, Town):-` and return the Name and Town only. `most_expensive(Name, Town):-` already does since I am checking the Price in the second predicate already I guess `home( Name, Town, Price)`.

Comment: I didn't quite get your meaning; it's probably best to post a new question with its code, sample query and desired output, etc. For instance, without the desired output, I wouldn't have guessed what you meant in *this* question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a simple solution if you think of the problem in the following way.

A person X meets your conditions if and only if X has a house in some city Y, and there is no one else in Y with a house costing at least half of the price of X's.

```erlang
% true if Name2's home is at least half of the price of Name1's
aboveHalf( City, Name1, Name2 ) :-
  home( Name1, City, P1 ),
  home( Name2, City, P2 ),
  Name1 \= Name2,
  P2 > P1 div 2.

superExpensive( Name ) :-
  home( Name, City, _ ),
  \+ aboveHalf( City, Name, _ ).
```