# Is there a way to reach the same result in a clause using less variables?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find/understand another way to reach a result by calling more predicates in a clause when using less free variables.

Coming from this problematic [How to correctly filter a clause that returns multiple duplicated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573203/how-to-correctly-filter-a-clause-that-returns-multiple-duplicated-values/) I wanted to try reaching to the same result adding a little difficulty.

```
Facts:
home(peter, sanFrancisco, 1000).
home(ash, sanFrancisco, 100).
home(juan, sanFrancisco, 400).
home(juan, california, 700).
home(ash, california, 600).
home(peter, california, 500).
home(peter, vegas, 100).
home(ash, vegas, 80).
home(juan, vegas, 60).

townHomesTotalCost(sanFrancisco, 1500).
townHomesTotalCost(california, 1800).
townHomesTotalCost(vegas, 240).
```

Answer provided in the previous question was very helpful and I wanted to try something different to understand better logic programming. Lets say that instead of the home price, I want to compare by percentage. For the percentage I created this clause:

```
townHomeCostByPercentage(Name, Town, Percentage):-
    home(Name, Town, Price),
    townHomesTotalCost(Town, Total),
    Percentage is round(((Price * 100) / Total)).
```

Getting the most expensive home in a town is such that no other home in that town is more expensive than it (Lets say I don't want to use the Price as an entry variable):

```
most_expensive(Name, Town):-
  home( Name, Town, Price),
  not((home( _, Town, P), P > Price)).
```

The second most expensive home in a town is such that is the most expensive among the homes which are not the most expensive home in that town:

```
second_most_expensive(Name, Town):-
  most_expensive(Name, Town),
  home(Name, Town, Price),
  home(_, Town, Price2), Price < TopPrice,
  not((home(_, Town, P), P < TopPrice, P > Price)).
```

I can't get why this is getting the same result as `most_expensive(Name, Town)`

And finally, using the percentage, return the Name but comparing percentage in that the most_expensive is < than the second_most_expensive + 20:

```
top_house_owner(Name) :-
  most_expensive(Name, T),
  townHomeCostByPercentage(Name, T, TopPercentage),
  second_most_expensive(_, T),
  townHomeCostByPercentage(_, T, Percentage),
  TopPercentage < Percentage + 20.
```

This also returning the results name of `most_expensive(Name, Town)` and can't get why.

Comment: Here is why: `second_most_expensive(Name, Town):-  most_expensive(Name, Town), ...` which means that `second_most_expensive/2` has **at most** the same solutions as `most_expensive`. Further, what do you expect if there are only homes for exactly the same price?

Comment: @false, I guess the first occurrence >= should be fine to not complicate it. As for the `second_most_expensive(Name, Town)` I should start with `home(Name, Town, Price)` and then try to "filter" it? I tried doing that but I always get repeated returned values and don't quietly get why.

Comment: The `foo(X), \+ (foo(Y), Y > X)` trick is a neat example of logic programming but it isn't particularly efficient or idiomatic. This problem kind of screams out for [library(aggregate)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate).

Comment: Your `top_house_owner/1` uses `second_most_expensive/2`, so if the latter is erroneous, so is the former also liable to be.

As posted, `second_most_expensive` can't possibly work at all. `TopPrice` isn't defined, yet used as if it were ground.

Besides, what information is conveyed by `second_most_expensive(_, T),` in `top_house_owner/1`? That there is *some* second most expensive house in the town `T`? What does it give us? Nothing at all.

And what information is conveyed by `most_expensive(Name, Town)`? That `Name` owns the most expensive home in the `Town`. But what is its price?

Comment: @WillNess, bad typo, home from `second_most_expensive` is `home(Name, Town, TopPrice)`. `second_most_expensive(_, T)` its terribly wrong as you said... I wanted to try in `second_most_expensive` getting the price with the Name that I got with `most_expensive` and compare. Something like:
get Name from the most expensive, get the price with the Name, get Name from the posible second most expensive, get the price with the Name of the posible second most expensive, compare prices and lastly it should return only the Name. The `most_expensive` its already returning the Name.